# Error in creating a pdf file android

Tags: android, itext

I am new to Android programming,my task was to create a pdf file in adroid

First I created a Java project using Eclipse (projectA) ,  wrote code in java to generate a pdf  file using itext (Added jars to the project) and its working fine.

Now I created another Android project (ProjectB) , and added the itext jars (similar to projectA) and code, but it is not working properly

```
Error : Error generating final archive: Found duplicate file for APK: com/itextpdf/text/LICENSE.txt
Origin 1: /home/SudheerB/workspace-Ecclipse/NeedAnalyserTool13/libs/itextpdf-5.3.3-sources.jar
Origin 2: /home/SudheerB/workspace-Ecclipse/NeedAnalyserTool13/libs/itext-xtra-5.3.3-sources.jar
```

Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very simple. You are using jar files which have some common classes. so during the generation of apk file, duplicates files are being found.

just use one of the jar files. either "itextpdf.jar" or "itextpdf-xtra.jar". your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the sources jars from your project and at least that error should go away.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response,
Yes, I removed the those jars from the project, error changed to

Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES

Comment: Hm, I don't know what that error means - you should google it or search here on SO. If you find no solution, post a new question, as it has nothing to do with creating PDFs anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're using the jars that are available for Java instead of the Android/GAE port. Please switch to using the official port for Android and Google App Engine. That will solve your problem. This port isn't available from SourceForge, you need to fill out the form at http://itextpdf.com/sales/ and they'll send you a link where you can download it.